# How should I move a cinemachine free look camera change it's position smooth slowly?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have one free look camera in a position when the game srart.

[image: Camera start position view height radius]

and I want that the camera smooth slowly to move from this current position a bit back to this position :

I changed the MiddleRig Height and Radius and also the MiddleRig Tracked Object Offset on the Y
And the Screen Y

[image: How the camera should be like after slowly moved]

but how can I do it in the game it self so the camera will change all this position/s and heights/radius smooth slowly ? Should I do it by script changing all the values of the properties of the camera ? or using a timeline somehow ?

In the end I want to move the camera a bit back that's the logic but to do it I have to change the free look camera height radius offset on the Y the screen y.

I wonder if there is any easier way to do it ? or the best way is to change all this properties in a script ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a SECOND virtual camera at the position that you want your viewpoint to end up.
Next, when you want your viewpoint to move, set the priority on that new camera to be higher than the priority of the free camera. This will tell the CinemachineBrain that you want to use the second camera. Hey presto, it will trigger a blended transition between the two.

The thing to remember is that Cinemachine cameras are not really cameras, they are just suggestions for where the actual **main scene camera** should be. Changing the relative priorities of the Cinemachine cameras tells the CinemachineBrain how to move the actual scene camera.